# zend framework multiple checkboxes should be inserted in database after i checked one or more of them

Tags: zend-framework

I have multiple checkboxes in zend ,I want that when i check them they are inserted into database .how to use that as an array and use for each to break them .I want to do this in my model insert them in in database.

Answer (score 0):

You can define checkbox names as array:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="1" /> option one
   <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="2" /> option two
   <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="3" /> option three
</form>
```

then, when you submit form, you should get your $_POST[check] variable filled in with ids of checked options. You can then foreach through this to insert into your table.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the array on your controller.

```
$chkArr=$this->_getParam('chkboxName');
```

After getting this you can pass this array to your model.
You can check the count etc. in model or controller depends on your requirement.